# Элементы словаря по условию

Tags: python, dict

Есть словарь

```
my_dict = {123: {'username': 'aaa', 'notify': 0, 'start_follow': 1500000000, 'end_follow': 1550000000},
          987: {'username': 'bbb', 'notify': 0, 'start_follow': 1600000000, 'end_follow': 1650000000}}
```

Нужен новый словарь  new_dict, в котором будут элементы(items) my_dict, удовлетворяющие условию:

'start_follow' > 1500000000

Comment: в чем вопрос/проблема?

Answer (score 2):

```
new_dict = {key: value for key, value in my_dict.items() if value['start_follow'] > 1500000000}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
my_dict = {123: {'username': 'aaa', 'notify': 0, 'start_follow': 1500000000, 'end_follow': 1550000000},
          987: {'username': 'bbb', 'notify': 0, 'start_follow': 1600000000, 'end_follow': 1650000000}}
array = [];
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    if (value['start_follow']>15*(10**8)):
        array.append(key)
        array.append(value)

new_dict = {array[i]: array[i+1] for i in range(0,len(array),2)}

print(new_dict)
```

Comment: Зачем такие извращения через список?

Comment: Сейчас отредактирую. Если пользователь знает, поменяет. Не помню как элемент в словарь добавить.